# receive "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" when use "require" keyword in google v8

Tags: javascript, v8, embedded-v8

I am new google to google v8.

I modified v8 hello world app.

```
const char* testJS = R"(
   var assert = require("assert");
   1 + 2;
)";
v8::Local<v8::Script> script = v8::Script::Compile(context, testJS).ToLocalChecked();
```

https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/5.8/samples/hello-world.cc

but got exception when running

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

So my question is, how could I
1) use 'require' in google v8
2) Make a custom common javascript class could be used as 'require(xyz)'

is they are related to v8::StartupData, but I don't know how to setup them correctly. Any advice would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149340/how-do-you-include-another-js-file-in-googles-v8

Answer (score 0):

The function `require()` is not a part of ECMAScript. If you need it, you have to implement it by yourself.