# How can I include another js file file in today's v8?

Tags: javascript, v8

I find an old anwser and later updates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149340/how-do-you-include-another-js-file-in-googles-v8), but it is hard for me to adapt this code to the latest(2020) V8 version.

There are many difficulties that I encounter:

1. `String::New` is removed and now a `String::NewFromUtf8Literal` needs an `Isolate* isolate` which I don't know how to pass to function `Include`, should I just add this before `const Arguments& args`?
2. `Script::Compile` takes a `Context` object as paramater now
3. And I don't know where to put the last two line codes

   ```
   Handle<ObjectTemplate> global = ObjectTemplate::New();
   global->Set(String::New("include"), FunctionTemplate::New(Include));
   ```

-- UPDATE --

After some work, I have my code like the [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mmh4VvNpNj/).

However, it still won't compile because of there errors:

1. Seems that I can't get a `Local` from a `Persistent`, even I have used [danijar's strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646546/how-to-store-persistent-handles-in-v8/22648552#22648552). Maybe it is because I have not used the constructor, but I don't think I can construct a Persist here inside this function scope.

   ```
   samples/import.cc:74:103: Error：cannot convert ‘v8::Local<v8::Context>’ to ‘v8::Context*’
      74 |     global_context = v8::Persistent<v8::Context, CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>>::New(isolate, local_context);
         |                                                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
         |                                                                                                       |
         |                                                                                                       v8::Local<v8::Context>
   ```
2. There are some errors with `String::NewFromUtf8Literal` here

   ```
   samples/import.cc:34:110: Error：‘static v8::Local<v8::String> v8::String::NewFromUtf8Literal(v8::Isolate*, const char*, v8::NewStringType, int)’ is private within this context
      34 |   Handle<String> source = String::NewFromUtf8Literal(args.GetIsolate(), buff, v8::NewStringType::kNormal, len);
         |
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to pass to function Include, should I just add this before `const Arguments& args`?

No, you can't modify the signature of functions that will be called from JS, but you don't need to: `FunctionCallbackInfo` (which is the replacement for `Arguments`) has a `GetIsolate()` method.

> `Script::Compile` takes a `Context` object as parameter now

Since you're having a question about this, I'm guessing you're only using a single Context for everything. Just store it in a `v8::Persistent`, and create a `v8::Local` from it whenever you need it. (For the time being, you can also use the deprecated `Isolate::GetCurrentContext()`, but for newly written code I would advise against that, as you'd only create more work for yourself in the future when you have to migrate away from it.)

> I don't know where to put the last two line codes

Wherever you're setting up the global object, somewhere in the startup sequence of your app.

All of these questions (and more) could be answered by studying the "shell" sample app that the V8 project maintains: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/samples/shell.cc.
In particular, its `Load` function does pretty much what you want.

Comment: Hi @jmrk, I have tried another time and now I have two other errors. Could you see my update?

Comment: (1) `global_context.Reset(isolate, local_context)` should work. (2) Use the public version of `NewFromUtf8Literal`, it has only 3 arguments.